# Rotation stabilization resulting in weird effect

Tags: tracking

I'm using version 2.92 of Blender and recently started learning it with the help of tutorials. This is what led to my problem:

1. I set up two track markers on an imported image sequence in the "Tracking" workspace.
2. I successfully perform the tracking of the markers all the way through the image sequence.
3. I successfully perform a "location stabilization" using the two track markers. This results in the video left/right and up/down on screen in order for the point between the two track markers to stay in one place on screen.

This to give some context.

Now, when I try to preform a "rotation stabilization" with the same two track markers, instead of the expected result (which, I assume, would be the image tilting to and fro to keep the rotation angle between track markers constant) I just get an empty image. Interestingly enough this image changes color when I scrub back and forth on the timeline.

What am I doing wrong? I haven't found any info so far about this anywhere.